# How to skip UAC allow app to make changes check when publishing an app?

Tags: windows, uac, codesign

I am publishing an application that runs as a Windows service. There are two executables involved: the servicemgr.exe (the Task tray UI for managing the service) and service.exe (the actual Windows service).

servicemgr.exe requires sufficient administrator permissions to be able to start, edit and stop the service. When the machine is booted, aside from starting the service, it loads the service management Task tray GUI (i.e. servicemgr.exe). However, when doing so, the servicemgr.exe program always comes up with the UAC prompt “Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?”.

Other task tray applets on Windows still get around this UAC prompt somehow. How do I package the servicemgr.exe file to open without prompting the user with this UAC related permission check? It seems even if I respond by allowing to run the application, the next time the OS starts up, it will ask the same question once again.

I code signed the application using a trusted digital authority, and the UAC prompt still appears. I tried editing the application manifest and adding trustInfo.. with execution level as requireAdministrator to no avail. (under asInvoker, the task tray application has insufficient privileges to manage the service)

Comment: servicemgr.exe is starting up on OS login by way of start item in registry key Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Comment: What code are you running in `ServiceMgr.exe` that triggers a UAC prompt? The `OpenService`/`StartService` functions will simply return `ACCESS_DENIED` if you didn't ACL the service correctly during install to allow **Everyone** to start/stop your service. In other words: it **won't** show a UAC prompt. Which leads me to believe your code, run by the user, is not calling `OpenService`/`StartService`. So how are you trying to start the service?

Comment: Additionally, is it an **actual** Windows **service**? Like an actual service that is registered as a service, a service that can be configured to automatically startup when the computer starts, and can be started with a call or `OpenService`/`StartService`? Or are you actually talking about a "helper" application that is manifested to to `requireAdministrator`? If that's the case, you need to change its manfiest so it does not try to run as an Adminstrator, but instead runs **"asInvoker"**. In order to proceed to an answer, we have to understand why the UAC prompt is appearing.

Comment: Thanks for your help in advance. I am using the Apache Procrun service manager. See: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html In the default install, the service is running under LocalSystem.

Comment: Well then you might be stuck trying to figure out where in that....Java?....code someone is calling **ShellExecute** and passing `runas`. Because **ShellExecute** is the only Windows function that knows how to launch `Consent.exe`, and pass it the required parameters to get elevated, and then it calls **CreateProcess**. Or maybe an executable has a manifest that has a **requestedExecutionLevel** of `requireAdministrator` or `highestAvailable`. You gotta get it to stop manifesting the app to launch as administrator, or get some code to stop calling **ShellExecute** with `runas`.